# Multiple dependent create statements in one processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 6 tables which I want to create one after the other - each successive table is dependent on the previous one.

I tried to put all 6 SQL scripts into one `PutSQL`-processor in Apache Nifi, but the processor failed when trying to create `table_2` with the error `table_1 does not exist`.

I'm guessing that changes are not committed to Redshift until the entire script is finished. I tried to get around it by activating `Database Session AutoCommit`, but I still get the same result.

Do I have to create 6 individual `PutSQL`-processors, or is there a way to put multiple SQL statements into one `PutSQL` processor and after each, the changes get committed to the databse?

Comment: I'm not an Apache Nifi expert and hopefully one can give you more direct information.  I do know Redshift and if I was attacking this I'd want to know the xid and pid of queries creating table_1 and table_2.  xid is the transaction id (commit block) and pid is the process id (connection id).  I'd guess that these statements are not coming from a single connection since auto-commit didn't help.  This info about the queries can be found in the stl_query table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is: I have to create 6 individual PutSQL-processors because of the constraints between Nifi and AWS-Redshift.